Unable to Trigger onChange Event in Text Fields Inside DataGridPro in React MUI
I'm currently facing an issue with handling the onChange event of text fields (TextField components) nested within a DataGridPro component in a React application. My goal is to capture user input within these text fields and update the state (formData) accordingly. However, despite setting up the onChange event handler within the renderCell function, the event is not triggering when the data in the text fields changes.
I tried to check it with multiple consoles and only console which is coming is

Rendering cell for field:

import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField, MenuItem, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
import { rowStyles } from './styles';
import PreviewForm from './previewForm';

const CreateForm = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleTestFormClick = () => {
    setFormData(optionRows[selectedOption]);
  };


  const renderCell = (params) => {
    const { field, value, row, api } = params;
  
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      console.log("handleChange function called for field:", field);
      console.log("Event:", event); // Log the event object
      const updatedRow = { ...row, [field]: event.target.value };
      api.updateRow(updatedRow);
      console.log("Updated Row:", updatedRow);
    };
  
    console.log("Rendering cell for field:", field); // Log when rendering cell
  
    return (
      <TextField
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log("onChange event triggered for field:", field);
          handleChange(event);
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  
  

  const columns = [
    { field: 'fieldName', headerName: 'Field Name', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell },
    { field: 'displayName', headerName: 'Display Name', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell},
    { field: 'fieldType', headerName: 'Field Type', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell },
    { field: 'location', headerName: 'Field Location', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell },
    { field: 'valuePath', headerName: 'Value Path', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell },
    { field: 'required', headerName: 'Is Required', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell },
    { field: 'defaultValue', headerName: 'Default Value', flex: 1, editable: true, renderCell: renderCell }
  ];

  const optionRows = {
    1: [
      { id: 1, fieldName: "title", displayName: "Post Title", fieldType: "string", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 2, fieldName: "description", displayName: "Post Description", fieldType: "text", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "No", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 3, fieldName: "author", displayName: "Author", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 4, fieldName: "category", displayName: "Category", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "No", defaultValue: "testing" },
    ],
    2: [
      { id: 1, fieldName: "name", displayName: "Name", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 2, fieldName: "email", displayName: "Email", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "No", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 3, fieldName: "phone", displayName: "Phone", fieldType: "string", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
    ],
    3: [
      { id: 1, fieldName: "username", displayName: "Username", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 2, fieldName: "password", displayName: "Password", fieldType: "password", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
    ],
    4: [
      { id: 1, fieldName: "title", displayName: "Product Title", fieldType: "string", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 2, fieldName: "description", displayName: "Product Description", fieldType: "text", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "No", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 3, fieldName: "price", displayName: "Price", fieldType: "number", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
    ],
    5: [
      { id: 1, fieldName: "name", displayName: "Name", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 2, fieldName: "email", displayName: "Email", fieldType: "string", location: "header", valuePath: "NA", required: "No", defaultValue: "testing" },
      { id: 3, fieldName: "message", displayName: "Message", fieldType: "text", location: "body", valuePath: "NA", required: "Yes", defaultValue: "testing" },
    ],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test ", formData);
  }, [formData]);

  return (
    <Grid container overflow="scroll" height="100vh" pb={8} pt={10}>
      <style>{rowStyles}</style>
      <Grid item md={1}></Grid>
      <Grid item md={10}>
        <Grid item md={12}>
          {!formData.length && <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleTestFormClick} style={{ float: 'right', marginBottom: '10px' }}>Test Form</Button>}
          {formData.length ? <PreviewForm formData={formData} /> : null}
        </Grid>
        {!formData.length && (
          <>
            <Grid item md={12} pb={2}>
              <TextField fullWidth label="Form Name" variant="outlined" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={12} pb={2}>
              <TextField
                fullWidth
                select
                label="Select API"
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={handleSelectChange}
                value={selectedOption}
              >
                {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(option => (
                  <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>Option {option}</MenuItem>
                ))}
              </TextField>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={12} pb={2}>
              <TextField fullWidth disabled label="Data Format" defaultValue="XML/JSON" variant="outlined" />
            </Grid>
          </>
        )}
        {selectedOption && !formData.length && (
          <Grid item md={12}>
            <DataGridPro
              rows={optionRows[selectedOption]}
              columns={columns}
              autoHeight
              disableColumnMenu
              disableColumnSelector
              getRowClassName={(params) => params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'even-row' : 'odd-row'}
            />
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default CreateForm;


Check this if this helps
Try creating a Customized component and rendering it in renderCell
